# Generation of Certificates with Attributes in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am following the instructions in the [docs](http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#fabric-ca-client) to generate an ecert with test attributes. But I am not being able to do it. I am using fabric-ca-client version 1.1.0-preview which according to this [issue](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5346), should have support for attribute certificates (I have also tried more recent versions).

What I do:

- Enroll the admin:

  $ export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca;
  fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054
- Register the client:

  $ fabric-ca-client register --id.name user1 --id.secret user1pw --id.type user --id.affiliation org1 --id.attrs attr1=val1:ecert
- Enroll the client:

  $ export FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca/clients/user1; fabric-ca-client enroll -u http://user1:user1pw@localhost:7054

But then, *openssl x509 -in /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca/clients/user1/msp/signcerts/cert.pem -text -noout* shows a certificate without attributes.

Questions:

1. Is it even possible to generate certificates with attributes using the fabric-ca-client utility? According to this [issue](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5346) "*The "fabric-ca-client register" CLI command will be enhanced to support* ...". But then, in the main documentation, it is explained as if it is already possible to do it.
2. If it is indeed possible, what am I doing (or may be doing) wrong? Since I am using the admin identity to register and enroll the new ecert, I assume there are no restrictions as to what attributes I may add to ecerts (however, I have also tried to follow the conditions stated [here](http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#registering-a-new-identity)).
3. If it is not possible, what is the recommended way to do it? Does generation with any of the SDKs work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

It turns out I was not using fabric-ca-client version 1.1.0-preview. With that version, the sequence of commands in the question correctly generate certificates with attributes.